# Can I remove a packet payload inside a .p4 program?

Tags: network-programming, switching, p4-lang

I would like to know if it's possible to completely remove a packet payload from a packet inside a .p4 program or at least modify it to random data. The reason behind this is that I'm cloning a packet and sending it to a different host (monitor) and this host does not need the packets payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what are you trying to do. If you would like to remove the some kind of header then it's enough to call

```
hdr.random_header.setInvalid()
```

if you call that in Egress it should remove fields of the header from the packet.
If you have len fields in headers you might also use

```
truncate(new_size)
```

when you know the size of packet without payload. If you already know easier option please share it here.

Comment: Hi, the option using truncate and updating each headers length field worked for me! Couldn't find any other. Thanks!!